# How to import Zbar Framework in Swift Project

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode6, zbar

I have a project and currently trying to convert to Swift project but I couldn't figure out how to present a Zbar barcode reader that scans from the camera feed.
On my current project I called like this

```
- (IBAction)scanButton:(id)sender {

    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    // present and release the controller
    [self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

**Note:
What I did so far**

1. Copy framework into the swift
2. Added framework path to the Header Search Paths (Targets Section > Build Settings)

   - $(PROJECT_DIR)/Test/ZBarSDK/Headers/ZBarSDK
   - Created Projectname-Bridging-Header.h for Bridging (added all h files from zbar)
   - Added Projectname-Bridging-Header.h to Header Search Paths

After that either if I write "import ZBarSDK" or ZBarReaderDelegate still gives me error!

Comment: This post solved my issue (GIF) http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/4059179

Comment: Who ever gonna try to add Zbar SDK also probably gonna face NSEnumeration problem.So for this function Use following ....     func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){var results: NSFastEnumeration = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults] as NSFastEnumeration} hope this help someone! Dont forget to extend!!  extension ZBarSymbolSet: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}

Comment: I have face the same problem

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/aeieli/swiftQRCode Need to change a few very simple syntax errors, otherwise fully working on iOS 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

following link helped me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/4059179

But after that I had NSEnumeration Problem so here second problem solution

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
var results: NSFastEnumeration = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults] as NSFastEnumeration
}
```

Don't forget to extend

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: SequenceType { public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator { return NSFastGenerator(self) } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for Swift 3:

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // ADD: get the decode results
        let results: NSFastEnumeration = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults] as! NSFastEnumeration

        var symbolFound : ZBarSymbol?

        for symbol in results as! ZBarSymbolSet {
            symbolFound = symbol as? ZBarSymbol
            break
        }
        let resultString = symbolFound!.data
        print(resultString)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have this [project](https://github.com/mfebrianto/ZBarSDK.Swift2.0)

Using cocoapods to import the **ZBarSDK** to Swift 2.0 project.