# Using zbar sdk and converting to swift 3, will it work?

Tags: swift3, zbar-sdk

I'm planning to convert the code to Swift 3 in xCode 8, but I'm hesitant to do so, because of the frameworks I use, especially ZBar SDK (I'm getting it with CocoaPods). Does anyone know, if the conversion can make this (or other) framework unusable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only changes should be the protocol part, you may refer to this post.

[How to import Zbar Framework in Swift Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138773/how-to-import-zbar-framework-in-swift-project)

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // ADD: get the decode results
    let results: NSFastEnumeration = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults] as! NSFastEnumeration

    var symbolFound : ZBarSymbol?

    for symbol in results as! ZBarSymbolSet {
        symbolFound = symbol as? ZBarSymbol
        break
    }
    let resultString = symbolFound!.data
    print(resultString)
}
```